# Pandas Calculate Median of Group over Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the Median of Groups over columns. I found a very clear example at

[Pandas: Calculate Median of Group over Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261838/pandas-calculate-median-of-group-over-columns)

This question and answer is the exactly the answer I needed.  I created the exact example posted to work through the details on my own

```
import pandas
import numpy

data_3 = [2,3,4,5,4,2]
data_4 = [0,1,2,3,4,2]

df = pandas.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A','A','A','A','B','B'], 
                       'COL2': ['AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','BB'],
                       'COL3': data_3,
                       'COL4': data_4})

m = df.groupby(['COL1', 'COL2'])[['COL3','COL4']].apply(numpy.median)
```

When I tried to calculate the median of Group over columns I encounter the error

```
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

If I do the exact same code with the only difference replacing median with a different statistic (mean, min, max, std) and everything works just fine.

I don't understand the cause of this error and why it only occurs for median, which is what I really need to calculate.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Bob

Here is the full error message. I am using python 3.5.2

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-af0ef7da3347> in <module>()
----> 1 m = df.groupby(['COL1', 'COL2'])[['COL3','COL4']].apply(numpy.median)

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    649         # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
    650         with option_context('mode.chained_assignment', None):
--> 651             return self._python_apply_general(f)
    652 
    653     def _python_apply_general(self, f):

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    658             keys,
    659             values,
--> 660             not_indexed_same=mutated or self.mutated)
    661 
    662     def _iterate_slices(self):

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _wrap_applied_output(self, keys, values, not_indexed_same)
   3373                 coerce = True if any([isinstance(x, Timestamp)
   3374                                       for x in values]) else False
-> 3375                 return (Series(values, index=key_index, name=self.name)
   3376                         ._convert(datetime=True,
   3377                                   coerce=coerce))

    /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
        231         generic.NDFrame.__init__(self, data, fastpath=True)
        232 
    --> 233         self.name = name
        234         self._set_axis(0, index, fastpath=True)
        235 

    /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)

   2692             object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   2693         elif name in self._metadata:
-> 2694             object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   2695         else:
   2696             try:

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in name(self, value)
    307     def name(self, value):
    308         if value is not None and not com.is_hashable(value):
--> 309             raise TypeError('Series.name must be a hashable type')
    310         object.__setattr__(self, '_name', value)
    311 

TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

Comment: @CodeCupboard How could this be a concern?  `np.median([1,2])` (even number of values) works as well as `np.median([1,2, 3])` (odd number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the series name at this stage is being interpreted as un-hashable, despite supposedly being a tuple. I think it may be the same bug as the one fixed and closed:

- **[Apply on selected columns of a groupby object - stopped working with 0.18.1 #13568](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13568)**

Basically, single scalar values in groups (as you have in your example) were causing the name of the Series to not be passed through. It is fixed in `0.19.2`.

---

In any case, **it shouldn't be a practical concern** since you can (and should) call `mean`, `median`, etc. on GroupBy objects directly.

```
>>> df.groupby(['COL1', 'COL2'])[['COL3', 'COL4']].median()
           COL3  COL4
COL1 COL2            
A    AA     2.5   0.5
     BB     4.5   2.5
B    BB     3.0   3.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Your comments were extremely helpful and resolved my problem.