# Pandas: Calculate Median of Group count over Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261838/pandas-calculate-median-of-group-over-columns):

I have a Pandas dataframe such as:

```
dfq = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['USER1', 'USER1','USER2','USER2','USER2','USER3'], 
               'COL2' : ['MONTH1','MONTH2','MONTH1','MONTH1','MONTH2','MONTH1']
               })
```

[image: Original Data Frame]

In general, this means everytime a customer uses the service, a record is added to the table with the user ID and the month. I need to know in average how many times customer use the service per month.

I can count the month occurrences like:

```
dfq.groupby('COL2').count()
```

[image: Count]

But, how do I get the averages from there?  Or is there a better way to do this?

My desired output would be something like this:

If I count the number of groups (months) and then divide by the total number of records I can get a raw average:

```
testcount = dfq.groupby('COL2').count()
len(dfq)
testcount/len(dfq)*100
```

[image: Average per month]

Which sort of gives me the answer but I find it to be a very raw process. Averages are not trustworthy, I'd like to be able to get some more stadistical information: medians and deviations for instance.

In other words, I would like what they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261838/pandas-calculate-median-of-group-over-columns) but in their case they are calculating over numerical values while my values are strings. I need to get insights like: **what is the median customer usage of the service per month**.

I hope that is clear.

Thank you!

Comment: are you calculating the average per *user* or per *month*?

Comment: Hi @MattR, I am calculating the average per month

Comment: I am a little confused by your question, is 3 a desired output in this example? If not could you edit and provide your desired output?

Comment: @Sebastian, I just added some more information. I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: df.groupby(['COL2'], as_index=False).count().describe() Is this anywhere near to your desired solution? I am stiil not sure what you need because you write about mean and then you calculate distribution.

Comment: You are not interested in customer as an individual right?

Comment: You could also plot the data after grouping/counting

Comment: Hi Sebastian. No, I am not interested on each individual person. You are right I could plot. I am trying to figure out a plot that actually makes sense. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider starting with:

```py
df=dfq.assign(cnt=1).groupby(list(dfq.columns), as_index=False)["cnt"].sum()
```

Then you open the window of opportunity for the operations you mentioned:

```py
res_mean=df.groupby("COL2")["cnt"].apply(np.median)

res_std=df.groupby("COL2")["cnt"].apply(np.std)
```

Which returns accordingly:

```py
COL2
MONTH1    1.0
MONTH2    1.0
Name: cnt, dtype: float64
COL2
MONTH1    0.471405
MONTH2    0.000000
Name: cnt, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Grzegorz Skibinski. I am going to give this a try and report back.